# Interesting inertia problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, string

Consider the following.

> A car is accelerating with acceleration $a$. A string is attached to the roof of the car and to the bottom of the string, an object of mass $m$ is attached. Given $\theta$, the angle between the vertical and the string (which is not $90^\circ$ due to inertia of the object).
>
> How to derive an expression for the acceleration $a$ of the car given $\theta$ and $m$?
>
> And when does  $\theta$ remain constant?

I found a similar [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21553/example-in-the-book-a-simple-accelerometer), but the answers to that post were too low quality (as is also evident by the fact that the user didn't accept any of those as solutions); so don't flag this post as a duplicate of that.

Comment: This is a common question with many solutions explained on the internet eg [Physics problem solving - hanging ball in an accelerating truck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a49WO42vQzE).

Comment: Draw FBD of object in frame of car(Non-inertial) and also include Pseudo Force in it. Balance forces in horizontal and vertical direction.

Comment: And what about the second question?

Comment: Two equations are $Tsin\theta=ma$ and $Tcos\theta=mg$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if we consider the x-component of the tension $Tsin(\theta)$ and given the car moves with acceleration $a$ then

$$ma - Tsin(\theta) =0$$

and so

$$a=\frac{Tsin(\theta )}{m}$$

for a mass $m$. Remember that the mass experiences an inertial force and so $a$ is the acceleration of the car and mass for an observer inside the car. We can write this in terms of theta as

$$\theta=sin^{-1}(\frac{ma}{T})$$ This tells us that $\theta$ will continue to increase if $a$ increases, and if the rope does not break, it appears that $\theta$ can take on any value from $0\le \theta \le 90$ degrees.

It could snap at some point $\theta$ but to calculate this we would need a maximum value for $T$. If $\theta =90$ degrees then you’d have the condition $$T-ma=0$$

Comment: Why not write $$\theta=arctan\Big(\frac{a}{g}\Big)$$ by balancing forces in vertical direction?

Comment: @joseph What is the expression for tension here?

Comment: We could have @user1000 but I wanted to keep the Tension symbol.

Comment: $T=mgcos\theta$ is wrong It should be $Tcos\theta=mg$.

Comment: @josephh On the other hand, why does a rod behave differently in this situation?(string replaced by rod)

Comment: That should have been T=mg/cos(theta).

Answer (score 1):

In summary, when $\theta$ is constant we have

$T \sin \theta = ma
\\ T \cos \theta =mg
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \tan \theta = \frac a g \text{ ; } T = m \sqrt{a^2+g^2}$